# Python - if a key is not in one list, append to another

Tags: python

This is probably a fairly simple one, but I haven't figured it out quite right.

I have two lists of tuples

List_A

`[('a', 0.033), ('b', 0.030), ('c', 0.020), ('d', 0.010), ('e', 0.005)]`

List_B

`[('a', 0.057), ('b', 0.065), ('w', 0.060), ('x', 0.040), ('y', 0.010)]`

I want to check if a key in List_A is in List_B. If it isn't, I need to append it to List_B; but the value needs to get set to 0.

So output of the above would be:

`[('a', 0.057), ('b', 0.065), ('w', 0.060), ('x', 0.040), ('y', 0.010), ('c', 0.000), ('d', 0.000), ('e', 0.000)]`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put keys from *List_B* in a set and then use a simple for loop:

```
A = [('a', 0.033), ('b', 0.030), ('c', 0.020), ('d', 0.010), ('e', 0.005)]    
B = [('a', 0.057), ('b', 0.065), ('w', 0.060), ('x', 0.040), ('y', 0.010)]

B_keys = {k for k, _ in B}

for k, _ in A:
    if k not in B_keys:
        B.append((k, 0.0))

B
#[('a', 0.057),
# ('b', 0.065),
# ('w', 0.06),
# ('x', 0.04),
# ('y', 0.01),
# ('c', 0.0),
# ('d', 0.0),
# ('e', 0.0)]
```

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: The decimal digits of your output is Not right. Well, one of elements in output should be `('d', 0.000)`,  not `('d', 0.0)` as like your output. Can you fix this problem?

Comment: @CHENJIAN I believe the second element in the tuple is a float number, so `0.0` is the same as `0.000`?

Comment: @Psidom Well, I admit that `0.0` is the same as `0.000`, and it is NOT the key point to this problem. BUT, if I want to print the output more stricter, that is a real question.